# How to navigation To Another Controller while presses pop up in Annotion?

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

[image]

I can open method while click on PIN, but I want call a Method while this BLACK POP UP is pressed, not the PIN.

How can I do So?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `rightCalloutAccessoryView` like

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString * identifier = @ "pinId" ;

    MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier ];
    if ( !pin &&(annotation != mapView.userLocation))
    {
        pin = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier ];
        pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"g_pin.png" ];
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;

            pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }
    pin.annotation = annotation;

    return pin;

}
```

You will get a button on right corner like

[image]

on tapping on this button this method will be called

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"Pin Tapped");
}
```

This will help you.....Enjoy

Comment: Welcome and feel free for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

use two delegate method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```